# Как правильно в mongoose искать кириллицу?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

как настроить поиск по киррилическому значению?

делаю так

```
model.find({ name: 'вася 1'}, 
    function(e,d){
        console.log('error:', e);
        console.log('data', d);
    }
);//.remove().exec();
```

возвращается:

> error: null
>
> data: []

если искать по другим поля, данные с name == 'вася 1' есть

Comment: Проблема актуальна, вы решили ее?

Answer (score 0):

Нашли решение какое нибудь? А то у меня похожая проблема, нашел строчку кода в `keyword.js` модуля `mongoose` которая ищет только латиницу - `matches = term.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g);`. Ищу вот так:

```
`Model
.find()
.field(options)
.keyword(options)
.filter(options)
.order(options)
.page(options,
  function (err, materials) {
    if (!err) {
      res.json(materials);
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    }
  });`
```

Comment: удалось решить, но у моя проблема была то ли в регистрозависимом поиске, то ли с кавычками, к сожалению более подробно не смогу подсказать